# How to paste static value, not dynamic value in VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

How do I change this piece of VBA code such that instead of =datewanted in the excel cell, I get the static value of the "datewanted".

```
ws.Range("A" & lastRowofA & ":A" & lastRow).Formula = "=datewanted"
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the Value property of the Range object instead of the Formula property:

```
ws.Range("A" & lastRowofA & ":A" & lastRow).Value = "datewanted"
```

If `datewanted` is a variable in your VBA code containing a value to be inserted into your cells, simply drop the surrounding quotes:

```
ws.Range("A" & lastRowofA & ":A" & lastRow).Value = datewanted
```